# Pull special files with ADB

Tags: android, adb

I have a rooted Android device and I need to pull everything to pc.

First try in DDMS File explorer did not work out, it hangs and has to be force closed.

Trying again in powershell with
`adb pull /`
skips "special files"
is there a way to pull everything including special files?

EDIT: I have tried booting in Engineer mode and Meta mode and I have tried to copy from shell
No success

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. Try booting the phone into FastBoot and then do adb pull. Some of the files might be in use while the phone is running and causing them to be skipped.
2. I haven't done this personally, but I would try to use adb to get to shell on the phone and copy the files that were skipped.

   ```
   adb shell
   ```

Comment: Tried booting in both Engineer mode and Meta mode but no luck so far. Also tried shell but they are still not accessible. I will come back if I find a solution, thanks anyway.